# use of ときては in this sentence

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

context is about drugging someone up to get them to more lively again for sexual purposes

> やがて反応が磨耗し、クスリを用いて復調したと思ったら**明後日の方向に電波を飛ばしまくりときては、単に溜まったから排泄するという感覚の方が近くなる。**
>
> before long her responses became dull, we used the drug, thinking that it would get her back to form.......  "電波" are recklessly fired two days into the future, on top of that, because the "電波"  and simply collected , a feeling of excrement is impending.

Honestly, i have no idea what this saying in the 2nd part, there some strange euphemism here?

i've read [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14172368874)

> この場合は「追加される」という意味で捉えると良いでしょう。先にある情報に後から来て加わるということです。

is this appropriate to apply to this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24096/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noun + とくる` is an exclamatory and emphatic set phrase which is like "you know what", "on top of that", "when it comes to ...", etc. See: [What does 「ときている」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24096/5010)

> - 彼はハンサムで、しかも金持ちときた。
> - 日本ときたら寿司でしょう！

Likewise, this ときては somewhat emphasizes the long noun phrase, クスリを用いて復調したと思ったら明後日の方向に電波を飛ばしまくり.

This ～と思ったら rougly means "soon after (realizing) ～", "once ～". 明後日の方向に is an idiomatic set phrase meaning "completely wrong direction", "in a totally unexpected way", etc. I'm not sure what this 電波 refers to, but it may be related to [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denpa).