# What does "絶っている" mean?

Tags: translation

> 街に戻ってきた者も
>
> 怯えきって人との関わりを絶っているときた

How does ときた work here? My understanding of the 2nd sentence's a bit rough.
I know "人との関わり" means "human interaction". What I'm not sure here is the function of "絶っているときた". I've only ever seen 絶っている like this. https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%B6%88%E6%81%AF%E3%82%92%E7%B5%B6%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62456/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24096/9831

Comment: You edited only the title of the question. Is you question about ときた, or 関係を絶っている, or both?

Comment: Sorry. It was both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The verb 絶つ has [various meanings](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%96%AD%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BB%E7%B5%B6%E3%81%A4-320742), and 関わりを絶つ ("to break off a relationship") is a common combination. ている describes the continuation of state (i.e., "has broken off").
- ときた/とくる (quotative-と followed by 来た) is an exclamatory phrase added after some surprising or extraordinary statement. It's hard to translate this literally, but it's "to go further", "on top of that", "even", "ha!" or something like that.

> 街に戻ってきた者も怯えきって人との関わりを絶っているときた。
>   Those who returned to the town are completely frightened and even have shut themselves away from people.